# Ubuntu 13.04 all apt-get mirrors down

Tags: 13.04, repository, mirrors

Apparently I can't get apt-get, as well as the ubuntu software centre, connect to any repository. I also tried to look for a suitable mirror using the ubuntu software centre (software sources->ubuntu software->download from->other->select best server), but it says it can't find any. My internet connection is OK (I'm writing here using the same pc on the same ubuntu), and there is no proxy.

Any ideas about what's going on?

Comment: I'd recommend a clean install.  It's possible to upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 then 14.04 but a fresh install will give you a cleaner system.

Comment: I agree with both Warren Hill and Wild Man, your best option is to upgrade to 14.04.

Comment: Warren Hill is correct when I said to upgrade I really should have said do a fresh install you will be a lot less likely to have issues.

Answer (score 14):

13.04 has reached EOL there for the repositories have been removed so there will be no more updates for 13.04 not even security so it is vulnerable to attacks.

There is an archive [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/) that you can use to install software but it will be old software outdated and there will be no improvements and no new security update.

If you want to use an outdated release then edit:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list and change `archive.ubuntu.com to old-releases.ubuntu.com`
```

By:

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I recommend upgrading.

Comment: Does it mean that I can't install/update anything anymore using apt-get?
Is it possible that there is no alternative? There is people who is using even older releases...

Comment: I added the information to use the archives since you want to use an EOL version.

Comment: @frakie, there is no other way. The only "old" release that is still being supported is 12.04 LTS - because it was the last LTS to be released with a support cycle of 5 years. That will end in 2017. The only other release (aside from 14.04 LTS) that is being supported still is 13.10 - but that will end later this year. It is better to go UP to 14.04 then it is to go DOWN to 12.04 however.

Comment: More information is available here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Comment: any idea when old-releases.ubuntu.com servers would be supported/online ?